# Receiving an Error with the Opencv Library for IOS

Tags: ios, opencv

Trying to do image processing for multiples .jpg files and write to one .jpg file using opencv library for an iOS app. But I'm not able to write/save to the final file (which I already have saved from the Resources folder to the Documents folder".

Getting the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension) in imwrite_, file /Users/Aziz/Documents/Projects/opencv_sources/trunk/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp, line 276
```

I could not find any solution.

Comment: You're probably going to need to show us the relevant code for us to help you out here.

Answer (score 1):

There's a high chance that your current OpenCV binaries wasn't built to support JPEG images.

Recompile OpenCV and make sure it is supported.